# 3 tier best practise - LinqTOSQL access in Presentation Layer

Tags: linq-to-sql, 3-tier

Scenario:
I have a scenario with a Presentation layer (ASP.NET), Business Logic Layer (dll) and Data Layer(dll) in the latter there is a LinqTOSQL DataContext file (dbml) which holds tables and stored proc for a particular database. The linking between projects are:

Dependencies:
Business Logic Layer has a reference for Data Layer
Presentation Layer has a reference for Business Logic Layer

My Problem:
The problem is that I have cases when I need to return an object of a table type corresponding to the datacontext, but since the Presentation Layer does not has a reference to the Data Layer I can't use the table object...Is it good practice to reference the Data Layer directly in the Presentation Layer? Or could someone guide me to the best way how I could achieve the Tables from the Presentation Layer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the business logic layer return a **`System.Data.Linq.Table<TEntity>`** to the presentation layer, have it return a **`System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TEntity>`** via implicit cast, or a **`System.Collections.Generic.IList<TEntity>`** by calling `ToList()` on the table.

It sounds like the objects defined in your dbml file are already in your domain namespace, so this way you don't have to reference `System.Data.Linq` in your presentation layer.